# Disambiguating version of Rust Futures APIs

Tags: support

Rust used to have an experimental futures v0.1 library for a while, and recently added futures to its standard library, but with a slightly cleaned-up API.

Many questions and answers on StackOverflow are still about the old API. This is problematic, because the APIs are similar enough that a novice may not notice the difference, but they are incompatible enough that old answers won't work for the new version of the library.

It's also annoying from SEO perspective, because both old and new futures are called the same, so it's infeasible to phrase a query in a way that reliably excludes the old version.

I can't personally manage to re-answer all questions with code for the new version.

1. Is it OK to use my post editing powers to add a note to existing answers that they're about the old futures v0.1 API?
2. Should there be separate tags for the versions, e.g. `rust-futures-experimental` and `rust-std-futures`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the convention is to add a comment in code blocks stating the version of the futures library used.

```rust
extern crate futures; // v0.1
```